# How to prevent users from removing QGIS layers?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I need to prevent users from removing layers. In my plugin code I use the following to achieve that:

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersWillBeRemoved.connect(self.dontremovefunc)

def dontremovefunc(self, layerids):
    QMessageBox.information(None,"Info!","Cannot remove layer!")
    return
```

But layers are removed.
What's the best option to prevent layer removal?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but maybe you have to disconnect the signal layersWillBeRemoved from the default slot removeMapLayers.

Comment: With `QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().layersWillBeRemoved.disconnect(QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().removeMapLayers)` I get `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not connected`

Comment: Not sure it makes sense, if you look at the code of removeMapLayers, it doesn't matter what you do with that signal, the next line of code calls the remove() method anyways http://qgis.org/api/qgsmaplayerregistry_8cpp_source.html#l00117